# EF4 Call stored procedure with multiple result sets

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have store procedure that return multiple result sets. I want to execute that SP using EF4 and get all the result sets data.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
using (var db = new customerContext())
{

    // Create a SQL command to execute the stored procedure
    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[GetAllCustomerAndOrders]";

    try
    {

        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        // Run the stored procedure
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // Read customer from the first result set
        var customers = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Customer>(reader, "Customers", MergeOption.AppendOnly);   


        foreach (var item in customers) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }        

        // Move to second result set and read orders
        reader.NextResult();
        var orders = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db)
            .ObjectContext
            .Translate<Order>(reader, "Orders", MergeOption.AppendOnly);


        foreach (var item in orders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.OrderNumber);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't try, but i think you can use it! but then you have to use Adapter and fill the DataSet and iterate through data tables.